# not possible to make normal package in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

In Eclipse I have two projects with the same package structure.
In one of them by mistake i delete the package.
When i Want to make structure I lost again I see this:

[image]

not this :

[image]

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the folder is in your build path.

Try right clicking it and choose "Build Path" > "Include".

Comment: it seems to be a solution, but when i want to delete the "old" package i get the message: Resource is out of sync with file system" and "Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since the source file /xxx/src/Main.java could not be read motsgame-desktop Unknown Java Problem"...

Answer (score 1):

You may be browsing in the Navigator view, not the Package Explorer view.